# Google Maps - Show address in marker in case of multiple markers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am using `google map api 3` to plot markers on the map on the basis of user input. I am getting address based on Zip Code from Database and its coming properly. I am using `geocoder` to convert address to `latlong` and again its correct too. Map are also being shown as desired but my problem start when I try to show user that which marker stands for what address, I am doing this using `title` property of `marker` but it is showing last address from array of many on every mark. My script is

```
var markers = response.d.split('^^');
            //var markers = ["Goregaon, Mumbai", "Malad, Mumbai"];
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.474634, -0.195791);
            var mapOptions1 = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: latlng
            }
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions1);
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i];
                // Geocoder area
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': data }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);


                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: data
                        });


                    } else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });

            }
```

Here I am passing two locations from `markers` array, i.e `Goregaon, Mumbai` and `Malad, Mumbai` and they are being plotted without fail :). But it I hover both red markers on map, on hover of both I am getting same value, i.e `Malad, Mumbai`. I tried putting `alert();` to see whats happening, I found code before entering `Geocoder Area` in the for loop is executing 2 time (size of array) and **then** `Geocoder Area` is executing 2 time (No serial execution), that is the reason behind showing `Malad, Mumbai` as a result because `title : data` always have `data = Malad, Mumbai` as a result of last iteration, however no one will like this outcome. True outcome will be when marker hover tell for what address they are for. How to do this?

**Solution**

Sorry MrUpsidown You were little late so I could not test your answer and found some another solution

Changed `title : data` to `title: results[0].formatted_address` worked for me. Big thanks for your response :)

**Update 1**

My code does not work for InfoWindow

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: distanceArray[j]});
                j++;
```

I tried

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: distanceArray[j];
j++;
});
```

Obviously, it won't work :(

Comment: That is because the geocoder is asynchronous. Your `for` loop ends before the geocoder has responded, therefore the value of `data` will always be the last one.

Comment: If you are fine with the response formatted address, then this is of course easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geocoder is asynchronous. Therefore your `for` loop ends before the geocoder gets a response. You can use another variable that you increment each time the geocoder returns a result (or an error) and use it to reference the correct `markers` array value.

```
var j = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

    // Geocoder area
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': markers[i]
    }, function (results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: markers[j]
            });

        } else {

            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }

        //Increment variable here
        j++;
    });
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/28pAr/)</kbd>

Comment: Answer appreciated and tested, it worth +1, but sorry I had found alternate already so not accepting, honesty :P

Comment: I applied the same thing with InfoWindow, but it giving unpected syntax "[" error

Comment: Where is the code? And if *your solution* worked, why not use the same one for the infowindow too?

Comment: My solution worked because google map exposed `formatted_address` field to set as a `title`, here I have nothing like that. my code is updated in question

Comment: Come on, we can't debug all your code for you! Did you log `distanceArray` somewhere? We don't even know what you put in there and what it looks like. Use `console.log()` and your javascript console. I gave you the same advice on another of your questions.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you sir, I will ask this as another question. Please give solution if possible... I am sorry for being so dumb.

Comment: It's not about being dumb. You have an error printing the value of an array. Show us what your array looks like (console.log) or at least how you created it and inserted the values in it. We can't guess that.

Comment: Sir, If you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735562/google-maps-multiple-infowindows