# Google Maps- Multiple InfoWindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have a javascript code as below

```
var markers = response.d.split('^^');
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.474634, -0.195791);
            var mapOptions1 = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: latlng
            }


            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions1);
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i];
                var lat = data.split('__')[0];
                var lng = data.split('__')[1];
                var addr = data.split('__')[2];
                var distance = data.split('__')[3];
                var newltlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                map.setCenter(newltlng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: newltlng,
                    title: addr
                });
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: distance });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                    }
                })
            (marker, i));

            }
```

After debugging code and seeing value, my markers array contains string item like

```
somelatitude1__somelongitude1__address1_distance1
somelatitude2__somelongitude2__address2_distance2
somelatitude3__somelongitude3__address3_distance3
somelatitude4__somelongitude4__address4_distance4
```

now when markers contain above 4 value I plotted markers for that. but in `InfoWindow` I am getting last element `distance` array for every marker because of its Asynchronous nature. I have no idea how to handle this and show proper values in corresponding markers. Thanks.

Comment: What does the input data look like? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the `infowindow` as argument to the function that returns the click-callback:

```
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (infowindow) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                }
            })(infowindow));
```